# Как открыть новую консоль, и ввести в неё команду

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Как можно реализовать через python открытие новой консоли и ввода в неё команды?
Например, команда python main.py; Результат консоли не нужен.
Допустим, я запускаю start.py, результатом этой программы будет открытие **новой консоли** и запуска в ней нового скрипта main.py; Консоль с скриптом start.py можно будет закрыть, при этом main.py продолжит свою работу, потому что он запущен в другой консоли, и обособлен от первой(start.py).

Я нашёл код, открывающий консоль, но как ввести после этого команду, найти не смог

```
import subprocess
x = subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd'], shell = True)
x.wait()
```

Comment: какую команду вы хотите ввести? есть ли смысл открывать консоль для этого?

Comment: @Dmitry Команда "python main.py"
Я хочу запустить отдельно новый скрипт python, и закрыть программу, которая его открывала, при этом, чтобы новый продолжил работу. В общем, открыть обособленно от открывающего скрипта

Comment: вывод будет направлен в консоль? входные аргументы будут у main?

Comment: @Dmitry Нет, аргументов не будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот способ:

```py
import os
os.system("start python main.py")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

А как насчет такого? Просто и не усложнять

```py
import subprocess
x = subprocess.run(['python', 'main.py'])
```

Если будут выходные данные

```py
import subprocess
x = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'main.py'])
print(x)
```

Соглсно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) можно пользовать `Popen`

```py
import subprocess
x = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'main.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print('out', out)
print('err', err)
print('returncode', p.returncode)
x.wait()
```

Comment: Возможно я делаю что-то не так, но main.py запускается в той же консоли. В этом случае, если я закрою программу с этим кодом, то и main.py завершит свою работу.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос детальное описание результата, который вы ожидаете

Comment: @Кирилл что вполне логично. Вы нигде не формулировали, что не должно закрываться.

Comment: @Dmitry Вопрос исправил. Пытался найти решение(и в документации, и на форумах), но результат тот же. Консоль открывается, команда выполняется, новый скрипт запускается, но при этом, я не могу закрыть начинающий скрипт, он ждёт завершения main.py. 
Скрипт в main.py для примера:
while True:
    input()

Answer (score 0):

Найти нормального решения, я так и не смог. Пришлось использовать "костыль" в виде pyautogui

```
import subprocess, time
import pyautogui as pag

x = subprocess.Popen(['start', 'cmd'], shell = True)
x.wait()
time.sleep(1) #чтобы компьютер успел открыть консоль
pag.typewrite("python main.py")
pag.press('enter')
```

Это ужасный способ, но работает. Единственное решение, которое я смог придумать за два дня поиска.
Если вы столкнулись с той же задачей, что и я, рекомендую найти решение получше.